# Can I include an image in an Excel report created from a sql query?

Tags: mysql, excel, report

I have to create an Excel report, based on a mysql query, which contains text columns. One of these columns stores the absolute path of an image. I'm wondering if would be possible to create the report including the image visible (as ole?).

Basically, in Excel, can I show the image If I have its path?

Comment: It is possible - using Excel VBA (or any other programming language that can manipulate the excel object model). But I'm not sure if it is a good idea. It would make the excel file huge, plus you would have to deal with image heights. Perhaps you could compromise by making it a hyperlink?

Comment: There are functions in PHPExcel library which allow you to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with PHPExcel.  Firstly you need to download the latest version: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

And here is an example of it's use:

```
include 'PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Jobin Jose");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Jobin Jose");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHPExcel classes.");

// Add some data
// echo date('H:i:s') . " Add some data\n";
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
//$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('uploads/t12.jpg');
// Add a drawing to the worksheetecho date('H:i:s') . " Add a drawing to the worksheet\n";
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('C1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') . " Done writing file.\r\n";
```

The above code will create an “xlsx” formatted file because it uses 2007 excel classes If you want “xls” format just try with 2005 class do not for get to change the file format to “xls” while using 2005.

See [here](http://www.walkswithme.net/writing-images-to-the-excel-sheet-using-phpexcel) for an example